# Update and Insert into SQL database using PHP

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sql-update, sql-insert

I am having some trouble getting my HTML table to insert and update into my SQL database using PHP. Not really sure where I am going wrong. It doesn't throw any errors, but doesn't seem to do anything either. The 'get', 'new' and 'delete' buttons are all working fine. I am trying to insert and update data as well as images. Thanks

```
<?php
$servername = "e0771987cert4rebeccagangemi.myitoc.com.au";
$username = "******";
$password = "********";
$message = "";
$teamID = "";
$Name = "";
$Logo = "";

if(isset($_POST["RetrieveTeam"])) {

getSpecificTeam($_POST["teamID"]);

    }

if (isset($_POST["NewTeam"])) { 
        resetTeamMaintenanceForm();
    }

if (isset($_POST["InsertTeam"])) {
        insertTeam();
    }

if (isset($_POST["UpdateTeam"])) {
updateTeam($_POST["teamID"]);
header("Location: admin.php");  
    }

if (isset($_POST["DeleteTeam"])) {
deleteTeam($_POST["teamID"]);
header("Location: admin.php");  
    }

function resetTeamMaintenanceForm() {
try {
    $teamID="";
    $TeamName="";
    $Logo = "";
    }
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "An error occured: " . $e->getMessage();
}
}

function getSpecificTeam($teamID) {

try {

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $GLOBALS ['servername'] . ";dbname=e0771987_Oaktown", $GLOBALS['username'], $GLOBALS['password']);

    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $statement = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM Teams WHERE teamID='" . $teamID."'");

    $result=$statement->fetch();

    if($result == null) { //ID doesn't exist

    $GLOBALS['message'] = "The ID entered is not valid or does not exist";

    } else {

        $GLOBALS['teamID'] = $result[0];
        $GLOBALS['Name'] = $result[1]; 
        $GLOBALS['Logo'] = $result[2]; 


    }
}

catch(PDOException $e) {

    echo "An error occured:" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
}
function insertTeam() 
{
try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $GLOBALS['servername'] . ";dbname=e0771987_Oaktown", $GLOBALS['username'], $GLOBALS['password']);

  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $tmp_image_name  = $_FILES["team_image"]["tmp_name"]; //get image file

    if (!isset($tmp_image_name)) { //file hasn't been selected
        echo "Please select a file to upload"; 

   } else {
        $check = getimagesize($tmp_image_name);  // check if file is an image type

        if ($check) { // if file is an image

  $statement = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Teams (teamID, Name, Logo) VALUES (:teamID, :Name, :team_image)");

  $statement->bindValue(":teamID", $_POST["teamID"]);
  $statement->bindValue(":Name", $_POST["Name"]);
  $statement->bindValue(":team_image", $tmp_image_name);
  $result = $statement->execute();
  if ($result) {
     echo "Team record inserted into table successfully";

  } else {
     echo "The team record was not inserted";
  }

} else {
    echo "The file to be uploaded is not an image";
}
}
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "A problem occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
}
function updateTeam($teamID) {
try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $GLOBALS['servername'] . ";dbname=e0771987_Oaktown", $GLOBALS['username'], $GLOBALS['password']);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $file_content = file_get_contents($_POST["Logo"]); 
  $statement = $conn->prepare("UPDATE Teams SET teamID=:teamID, Name=:Name, Logo=:Logo WHERE teamID='" . $teamID."'");

  $statement->bindValue(":teamID", $_POST["teamID"]);
  $statement->bindValue(":Name", $_POST["Name"]);
  $statement->bindValue(":Logo", $tmp_image_name);

  $result = $statement->execute();
  if ($result) {
     echo "Team record was updated";
  } else {
     echo "The team record was not updated";
  }
 }
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "A problem occured: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
}

function deleteTeam($teamID) {
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $GLOBALS['servername'] . ";dbname=e0771987_Oaktown", $GLOBALS['username'], $GLOBALS['password']);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $statement = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM Teams WHERE teamID='" . $teamID. "'");

   $result = $statement->execute();
   if ($result) {
     $GLOBALS['message'] = "Team record was deleted successfully";
   } else {
     $GLOBALS['message'] = "The Team record was not deleted";
   }
 }
 catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "A problem occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
 }

 $conn = null;
}

?>

<div id="Edit Teams">
<p id="TableHeader2">Update or Delete Teams</p>


<table style="width:66%"

    <tr>
    <td style="width:30%"><b>teamID</b></td>
    <td colspan=2><input type="text" style="width:350px" name="teamID" value="<?php echo $teamID;?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="width:30%"><b>Name</b></td>
    <td colspan=2><input type="text" style="width:350px" name="Name" value="<?php echo $Name;?>"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><b>Logo</b></td>
<?php   
     $image = NULL;
     $image = $Logo; 

    if(isset($image) && !empty($image)) {
                            //echo "<td><img src='images/" . $teamRecord['Logo'] . "'/></td>";
echo '<td><img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode( $GLOBALS['Logo']  ).'"/></td>';   

} else { ?>

<td><input type="file" name="logo" value=""></td> 

<?php }
?>
<!--td><input type="file" name="logo" value=""></td--> 
        </tr>


  </table><br>

<input class="button" type="submit" name="NewTeam" value="New">    
<input class="button" type="submit" name="InsertTeam" value="Insert">
<input class="button" type="submit" name="RetrieveTeam" value="Get">
<input class="button" type="submit" name="UpdateTeam" value="Update">
<input class="button" type="submit" name="DeleteTeam" value="Delete">
    </div>
```

Comment: you does to change your database password because you put it in the code and it's really a bad practice

Comment: thanks, I realised and was trying to edit the post.

Comment: i'll edit it before past my comment :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you has this complete code in one file... you have to split it in others more readable, this will permit you detect errors easily.

for example..

```
class PdoMysqlConnection
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $settings;

    /**
     * @var \PDO|null
     */
    private $linkid;

    public function __construct($settings = array())
    {
        $this->settings = $settings;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $connection
     * @return $this
     */
    public function connect($connection){
        try{
            if(!isset($this->settings[$connection])){
                throw new \Exception('The connection '.$connection.' is not defined in the parameters');
            }
            $this->linkid = new \PDO(
                'mysql:dbname='.$this->settings[$connection]['db'].';host='.$this->settings[$connection]['host'],
                $this->settings[$connection]['user'],
                $this->settings[$connection]['password'],
                array(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
            );
            if (!$this->linkid){
                throw new \Exception("Cant not connect with Mysql.");
            }
            return $this;
        }
        catch (\Exception $ex) {
            var_dump($ex->getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * close connection
     * @return $this
     */
    public function close(){
        try{
            $this->linkid = null;
            return $this;
        } catch (\Exception $ex){
            var_dump($ex->getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $sql
     * @return \PDOStatement
     */
    public function query($sql){
        try{
            $query = $this->linkid->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute();
            return $query;
        }
        catch (\Exception $ex){
            var_dump('Error query: '. $query->queryString);
            var_dump($ex->getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param \PDOStatement $query
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasResult($query){
        if($query->rowCount() > 0){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param \PDOStatement $query
     * @param null $first
     * @return array
     */
    public function fetchArray($query, $first = null){
        if($first){
            return $query->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
        return $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    /**
     * @param \PDOStatement $query
     * @param null $first
     * @return array|object|\stdClass
     */
    public function fecthObject($query, $first = null) {
        if($first){
            return $query->fetchObject();
        }
        $rows = array();
        while ($row = $query->fetchObject()){
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        return $rows;
    }

    /**
     * @return int|string
     */
    public function getLastInsertedId(){
        return $this->linkid->lastInsertId();
    }
}
```

This class will give you a complete use for database transactions, and the next class is you Team class...

```
class Team{

    private $pdoConnection;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->pdoConnection = new PdoMysqlConnection($GLOBALS['db_settings']);
        /**
         * mysql2 is the name of your connection, you can define multiple 
         * connection with a multiarray setting
         */
        $this->pdoConnection->connect('mysql2');
        return $this;
    }

    public function insertTeam(){
        $this->pdoConnection->query("INSERT .... YOU CODE");
        return $this->pdoConnection->getLastInsertedId();
    }

    public function selectTeam(){
        $query = $this->pdoConnection->query("SELECT .... YOU CODE");
        return $this->pdoConnection->fetchArray($query);
    }

    /**
     * the rest of your code is in here
     */
}
```

And them you HTML...

Another tip... you have to know the stackoverflow community don't have your complete development environment so you need to be more specific about your questions, and don't put questions like... I don't not why is not working.